# Two divs in Same Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have nested `divs`, I have to show it in same row please help me.

Also tell me how to show the progress bar in the place of `label id = "remainingcount"` while processing.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="listbox">
    <asp:Label ID="headertext" runat="server" CssClass="labelresul" Font-Bold="true" Height="50" Text="Available Filter"></asp:Label>
    <span style="padding-left:10px;font-weight:700;">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdCount" />
        <asp:Label ID="Total" runat="server" Height="50"></asp:Label>
    </span>

    <span style="padding-left:5px;font-weight:700;">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="match" Visible="false" Text="Matches"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="remainingcount" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="remaining" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Results"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </span>

    <div id="divv">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updFilters" runat="server" >
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <center>
                <asp:Panel ID="resultspanel" runat="server"> 
                    <img alt="Processing" src="Images/waiting_process.gif" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </center>
        </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `"style=float:left"` for both or try `bootstrap`

Answer (score 2):

Set both Div style as

```
.DivStyle{
   Display: Inline-block;
}
```

add this property to both

Answer (score 0):

HTML content :

```
<div class='container'>
<div class="align-left">left</div>
<div class="align-right">right</div>
</div>
```

Style as shown below

```
.container { 
 width:100%; }

.align-left { 
 float: left;
 width:50%; 
 } 

 .align-right{
 float: right; 
 width:50%
 }
```

Comment: this is ugly solution, better suggestion not to use a `*float(left|right)*`

Answer (score 0):

Set **float** for the div.

```
float:left
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st Way**

You can use `display: inline` to put the two `div` elements inline.

Explanation: `div` elements are block elements, so their display style is usually `display: block`.

```css
#box1 {
  width: 1005px;
  height: 1000px;  
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 162px;
  background-color: white;
}

#box2{
  width: 280px;
  height: 250px;  
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;

}
#box1, #box2
{
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
</div>


<div id="box2">
</div>
```

---

**2nd way**

You can wrap both the `div` elements in a `span` tag.

Explanation: `span` works the same way as the `div`, to organize and group elements. The only difference is that `span` is an inline element, so styling the `span` will not be needed. The display style of the `span` element is usually `display: inline`.

```css
.box2 {
  width: 280px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<span>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div></span>
```

**Note**: If the `span` doesn't work, it means that the content of your `div` tags cannot fit on one line. You are going to need to resize your `div` tags if that happens.

Sorry, I used my own example, but if you find the snippets confusing, please ignore them. Thank you for reading my answer! It took quite some time to write this and I hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it with

----CSS----

```
.main-div{
display: grid; 
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
}
```

----HTML----

```
<div class="main-div">
   <div/>
   <div/>
</div>
```